# Mysqli code output explanation

Tags: php, mysqli

can u please explain why the output results this way? I want to know why the array is included. I can't see any array words in the program. How did this happen? How could i output only the "1".

CODE:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") ||
!$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)") ||
!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1)")) {
echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p") ||
!$mysqli->query('CREATE PROCEDURE p() READS SQL DATA BEGIN SELECT id FROM test; SELECT id + 1 FROM test; END;')) {
echo "Stored procedure creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$mysqli->multi_query("CALL p()")) {
echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
    printf("---\n");
    var_dump($res->fetch_all());
    $res->free();
} else {
    if ($mysqli->errno) {
        echo "Store failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
}
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
?>
```

RESULT:

```
---
array(3) {
[0]=>
 array(1) {
[0]=>
string(1) "1"
}
}
```

I've deleted the other outputs anyway i just only want to know why the array is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli's fetch_all returns an array. From the documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php you can see the return value is "Returns an array of associative or numeric arrays holding result rows." So, you get an array. What you have is 1 row (as an array) with 1 value (in an array) with a value of "1".

Answer (score 0):

Notice as per the documentation - the return type for `mysqli_result::fetch_all`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-returnvalues